# Why launchOptions is nil after receiving push notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

What are possible reasons of receiving `nil` in `didFinishLaunchWithOptions` after getting a push notification and opening an app by tapping on the notification? I've double-checked that app is stopped, not just in background. And `nil` is still always written to log.

I'm not doing anything special in my `didFinishLaunchWithOptions`, here's the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [MA init];
    NSLog(@"%@", launchOptions);
    if (!launchOptions) {
        return YES;
    }
    id userInfo = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    if (userInfo[@"aps"] && userInfo[@"id"]) {
        MAResult* result = [[MA data] resultById:userInfo[@"id"]];
        if (result) {
            [((UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController) pushViewController:[[MATaskDetails alloc] initWithResults:result] animated:YES];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: What do you have inside the payload ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with didReceiveRemoteNotification delegate method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
   didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
[MA init];
    NSLog(@"%@", Received Notification);
    if (userInfo[@"aps"] && userInfo[@"id"]) {
        MAResult* result = [[MA data] resultById:userInfo[@"id"]];
        if (result) {
            [((UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController) pushViewController:[[MATaskDetails alloc] initWithResults:result] animated:YES];
        }
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps you....!

Answer (score -1):

If the app is in foreground mode then it receive push notification via `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`

But if the app is not in foreground mode push notifications are passed to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

So I believe you app in in foreground mode and the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
is not called at all.